Asymptotic expansion when E-M formula fails
I want to compute the asymptotic expansion of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+t\sin(2\pi k/n)}
$$
when $n\to\infty$ and parameter $0<t<1$.
I tried to use $f(x/n)$ in the Euler–Maclaurin formula, with $f(x)=\sqrt{1+t\sin(2\pi x)}$ as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nf\Bigl(\frac kn\Bigr)-n\int_0^1f(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{B_k}{k!}\frac{f^{(k-1)}(1)-f^{(k-1)}(0)}{n^{k-1}}+R_p
$$
However, for my specific $f(x)$, $f^{(k)}(1)=f^{(k)}(0)$ for all $k$, so all terms in the sum on the right vanishes and I get no information. I think this means that the remainder vanishes faster than any polynomial, presumable exponentially.

Update
I tried to directly evaluate the sum using either series expansion in $t$ or Fourier series. I found both methods yields that the sum is strictly equal to the integral $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ (which evaluates to elliptic integrals, but it does not matter). Numerically, this is not true. I did not find any apparent mistakes, as the sum over $k$ is finite and can always commute with limit.
I sketch the approach using series expansion. For $t<1$,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}rt^r(\sin x)^r
$$
Summation over $k$ yields
$$
\color{gray}{\sum_{k=1}^n(\sin(2\pi k/n))^r=\begin{cases}
0 & r\  \mathrm{odd}\\
\frac n{2^r}\binom{r}{r/2} & r\ \mathrm{even}\\
\end{cases}}
$$

Edit:
The gray formula above is not correct. (Do not blindly believe in Mathematica) The correct one is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(\sin(2\pi k/n))^{2r}=\frac n{4^r}\sum_{s\in\mathbb Z,|s|\le 2r/n}\binom{2r}{r+ns/2}
$$
The further conclusion below is thus false, so is deleted. This is not directly related to the question anyway.


Question: How can I calculate the asymptotic expansion, at least to the first order?
I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Did you tried the Abel summation formula? Maybe it can be useful, in this case. Anyway, I would expect terms that depend, in some way, on complete elliptic integrals of the second kind.

Some checks with WA. It seems that the rough formula (above) gives the correct order of magnitude - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=6%5Cint_0%5E1+%5Csqrt%7B1+%2B+0.5%5Csin+%282%5Cpi+x%29%7Ddx and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B6%7D%5Csqrt%7B1%2B0.5%5Csin%282%5Cpi+k%2F6%29%7D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%7B-6%5Cln%282%2B%5Csqrt3%29%7D

Also https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=6%5Cint_0%5E1+%5Csqrt%7B1+%2B+0.7%5Csin+%282%5Cpi+x%29%7Ddx and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B6%7D%5Csqrt%7B1%2B0.7%5Csin%282%5Cpi+k%2F6%29%7D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%7B-6%5Cln%281%2F0.7%2B%5Csqrt%7B1%2F0.49-1%7D%29%7D

Notice that $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac1{4^r}\binom{2r}{r}\binom{1/2}{2r}t^{2r}=, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;t^2\right)$$

@ClaudeLeibovici I know that the sum is hypergeometric (and can be reduced to   a complete elliptic integral). The exact form does not matter anyway.

@RiverLi The summation is a finite sum for fixed $n$. Of course it can commute with integrals or series.

@Svyatoslav Thank you for you remark. I was actually aware of my mistake, but have no time to edit. Now I correct that part.

Have you tried using the exact expression for $R_p$ as a starting point for estimating it?

Right now I cannot get asymptotis of your sum, but I can explained in details what is happening - using similar example $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^n\sqrt{1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n}$$ This case is easier to investigate, and I got its asymptotics. I was right about the method of evaluation and general view of the additional asymptotic term, but I looks a bit complicated and has additional factors. Checked numerically - it works perfectly. So, if you are interested, I will post it. Please, let me know.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n}-n\int_0^1\sqrt{1+t\sin(2\pi x)},dx\sim-,\frac{\cos\frac{3\pi n}2}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}t\right)^{-n}(1-t^2)^\frac14$$
It seems that WA (free option) confirms. Could you please check, using more serious source? Thank you.

@Gary, could you prove or disprove the asymptotics above? I got it by very unjustified means and not sure whether it works... I believe there sould be a regular approach. Many thanks in advance!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

When the function is periodic the Riemann sums approximate the integral with exponentially decreasing error term and the EM formula doesn't work. See this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3490868/72031 (specially discussion in comments).

Just in case to the discussion. The straightforward solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4951182/sum-of-sum-i-0n-1-frac1a-sin2-fracij-pin/4951680#4951680 gives for any  $a>0$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{a+\sin^2\frac{\pi k}n}=\frac n{\sqrt{a(1+a)}}\frac{\big(1+2a+2\sqrt{a(1+a)},\big)^n+1}{\big(1+2a+2\sqrt{a(1+a)},\big)^n-1}\overset {,a=\frac18}{\Rightarrow}\frac{8n}{3}\frac{2^n+1}{2^n-1}$$

Very interesting problem indeed! It is late at night, so I apologise in advance for any typo :)
Let' consider (just to note that we start summation from $k=0$)
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n\right)^{-\alpha}$$
where we chose for a while $0<\alpha<1$
In a standart way, switching to complex integration
$$2\pi iS=\pi t^{-\alpha}\oint_C\cot\pi z\left(\frac1t+\sin\frac{2\pi z}n\right)^{-\alpha}dz=\pi t^{-\alpha}\oint_C\cot\pi z\left(\cosh\frac{2\pi s_0}n+\sin\frac{2\pi z}n\right)^{-\alpha}dz$$
where $\,s_0=\frac{n}{2\pi}\operatorname{arch}\frac1t=\frac{n}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac1t+\sqrt{\frac1{t^2}-1}\right)$, and the contour $C$ embraces the points $z=0,1,2,...n,\,$  . As we have two branch points $z=\frac{3n}4\pm is_0$, we deform the contour and integrate along the following way (adding two cuts and keeping the integrand an analytical function)

Integrals along the paths 1 and 2 cancel each other; at $z\to\pm i\infty$ the integrand declines exponentially, so the integral along the horizontal paths tend to zero, and we are left with the integrals along the paths A,B,C,D (and, of course, the half-residues at the points $z=0, n$)
Hence,
$$2\pi iS=2\pi i+I_A+I_B+I_C+I_D$$
Appointing the phases to the paths at $z\to\pm i\infty$, and taking into account the change of phases while turning around the branch points
$$2\pi iS=2\pi i-\frac{1-e^{2\pi i\alpha}}{e^{\pi i \alpha}}\pi t^{-\alpha}i\int_{s_0}^\infty\cot\pi\big(\frac{3n}4-is\big)\left(\cosh\frac{2\pi s}n-\cosh\frac{2\pi s_0}n\right)^{-\alpha}ds$$
$$+\frac{1-e^{-2\pi i\alpha}}{e^{-\pi i\alpha}}\pi t^{-\alpha}i\int_{s_0}^\infty\cot\pi\big(\frac{3n}4+is\big)\left(\cosh\frac{2\pi s}n-\cosh\frac{2\pi s_0}n\right)^{-\alpha}ds$$
Given that $n\gg1\,\,s_0\gg1$, and we can decompose $\cot$ near this point (just to mention that such decomposition allows to get full asymptotics). Keeping only two terms,
$$\approx 2\pi i+4i\sin(\pi\alpha)\,\pi t^{-\alpha}\int_{s_0}^\infty\left(1+\cos\frac{3\pi n}2e^{-2\pi s}\right)\left(\cosh\frac{2\pi s}n-\cosh\frac{2\pi s_0}n\right)^{-\alpha}ds$$
$$=2\pi i+4i\sin(\pi\alpha)\,\pi t^{-\alpha}(I_1+I_2)$$
To evaluate $I_2$, we use again the condition $n\gg1$:
$$\int_{s_0}^\infty e^{-2\pi s}\left(\cosh\frac{2\pi s}n-\cosh\frac{2\pi s_0}n\right)^{-\alpha}ds\approx e^{-2\pi s_0}\int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi s}\left(\sinh\big(\frac{2\pi s_0}n\big)\,\frac{2\pi}ns\right)^{-\alpha}ds$$
$$=e^{-2\pi s_0}\left(\sinh\big(\frac{2\pi s_0}n\big)\right)^{-\alpha}\frac{n^\alpha}{2\pi}\Gamma(1+\alpha)$$
To evaluate $I_1$, we make the following transformations:
$$\int_{s_0}^\infty\left(\cosh\frac{2\pi s}n-\cosh\frac{2\pi s_0}n\right)^{-\alpha}ds=\frac n{2\pi}\int_{\operatorname{arch\frac1t}}^\infty\left(\cosh x-\frac1t\right)^{-\alpha}dx$$
$$=\frac n{2\pi}\int_{\frac1t}^\infty\frac{\big(x-\frac1t\big)^{-\alpha}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\frac{nt^\alpha}{2\pi}\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{-\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1-t^2x^2}}dx$$
But
$$\sin\pi\alpha\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{-\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1-t^2x^2}}dx=\pi\int_0^1\left(1+t\sin(2\pi x)\right)^{-\alpha}dx$$
I leave this to be rigorously proved by those who are interested; myself, check via decomposition and integration term by term (and confirmed numerically).
So, taking all together, we get the answer:
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n\right)^{-\alpha}\approx 1+n\int_0^1\big(1+t\sin(2\pi x)\big)^{-\alpha}dx$$
$$+t^{-\alpha}\sin(\pi\alpha)\cos\frac{3\pi n}2n^\alpha e^{-2\pi s_0}\sinh^{-\alpha}\left(\frac{2\pi s_0}n\right)\Gamma(1+\alpha);\,\,\alpha\in(0,1)$$
Implementing analytical continuation, we can consider any real $\alpha$. For example, taking $\alpha=-\frac12$ we get the asymptotic that I mentioned in the comment (and that initially found by not rigorous way). Just expressing $s_0$ via $ n, t$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n\right)^{\frac12}\sim n\int_0^1\big(1+t\sin(2\pi x)\big)^\frac12dx-\frac{\cos\frac{3\pi n}2}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(1-t^2)^{\frac14}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}t\right)^{-n}$$
In the case of odd $n$ we have to consider next terms of the decomposition of $\cot\big(\frac{3\pi}4\pm is\big)$ to find non-zero asymptotic terms.
Numeric checks with WA confirm the result (just one point: you have to evaluate $\,\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n\right)^{\frac12}\,$ and $\,n\int_0^1\big(1+t\sin(2\pi x)\big)^\frac12\,$ numerically separately, and only then take the difference. If you put $\,\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n\right)^{\frac12}-n\int_0^1\big(1+t\sin(2\pi x)\big)^\frac12\,$ in WA, the number may be not correct. These are bugs of WA free option.)

There is also a more rich case of alternating series (I also mentioned it in the comment). Using complex integration we can get, for example,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\sqrt{1+t\sin\frac{2\pi k}n}\sim\frac{1+(-1)^n}2+\big((-1)^n-1\big)\frac{\pi t}{4n}\left(1+O\Big(\frac 1{n^2}\Big)\right)$$
$$-\,\sqrt{\frac 8{\pi n}}\cos\frac{3\pi n}4(1-t^2)^\frac14\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}t\right)^{-\frac n2}$$
Here I keep the exponentially small term just to show that it contributes at even $n$

Amazing! The result seems to agree numerically using Mathematica. I will check the details later.

+1 but corrections needed (upper limit of summations, fractions under $\color{blue}{\sin}$, etc.)

@metamorphy, thank you very much for your time and help! I corrected a bunch typos. I wish you a nice day!
